# Sympy - ufuncify a vector function

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numpy-ufunc

I have lambdify-ied a vector function of a modified [FitzHugh–Nagumo model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitzHugh%E2%80%93Nagumo_model) (with no diffusion terms):

```
from sympy import symbols, Matrix, solve, Eq
from sympy import diff, simplify, lambdify
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify


u, v , e, a0, a1 = symbols('u v e a0 a1')

dudt = u - u**3 -v
dvdt = e*(u - a1*v - a0)

eqs = Matrix([dudt,dvdt])
print eqs

numerical_eqs = eqs.subs([(e,1.0),(a0,0.5),(a1,1.0)])
print numerical_eqs
lambdify_eqs = lambdify([u,v], numerical_eqs)
print lambdify_eqs(1.0,0.5)
```

But trying to produce a `ufunc` in the same way results in an error:

```
ufuncify_eqs = ufuncify([u,v], numerical_eqs)
```

The error message that I get ends with:

```
CodeGenArgumentListError: ('out_817415551552344190', [<sympy.utilities.codegen.OutputArgument object at 0x7f8da54dccd0>])
```

Someone knows what is the right way to [ufuncify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html) a vector function?

Comment: Relates SymPy issue https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10522

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that ufuncify supports SymPy Matrices as the expression yet. You can do each expression in the matrix individually.